# error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate.status.tmp: Permission denied

Tags: centos7, logrotate

I am trying to logrotate my log files. Here is my configuration file:

```
/home/deploy/apps/production_app/current/log/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 52
    compress
    create 0644 deploy deploy
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    sharedscripts
    copytruncate
}
```

And this is result of

> ll apps/production_app/current/log/

on my log files:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy        0 Jul  1 10:01 production.log
-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy  1124555 Jul  1 10:01 production.log.1
```

And when I run this command

> logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/production_app

I get following:

> error: error creating output file /var/lib/logrotate.status.tmp:
> Permission denied

Comment: under the context of which user do you run this command?

Comment: I run it under deploy user

Comment: `/var/lib` is only writable by root, run logrotate as root.